# Permanent command alias

Tags: 14.04, shortcuts, alias

I want to create permanent alias for running some long comments of Django, for example for running django server now I use:

```
$ cd test/
$ . bin/activate
$ cd project
$ python manage.py runserver 4321
```

How can I shorten all of them just as permanent command to: `pyrun`
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply paste the following lines in your `~/.bashrc` file and open a new terminal (or restart your shell):

```
pyrun()
{
    cd ~/test/
    . bin/activate
    cd project
    python manage.py runserver 4321
}
```

Comment: I would have put a script in `/usr/local/bin` and added the alias to `/etc/bash.bashrc`, so all users can benefit from the change, but this'll work too! (so still upvoted!)  **;-)**  (Hint, hint, ...)

Comment: Note that this answer defines `pyrun` as a shell function, not an alias. To be clear, that's not a problem, even though the OP mentioned wanting to make an alias--using a shell function instead is a *strength* of this answer. [Functions are considerably more versatile (and often more readable) than aliases.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do.

- Open Terminal
- Run `vi ~/.bashrc`
- Press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter the
  input mode
- Add this line

  ```
  alias pyrun='cd test && .
      bin/activate && cd project && python manage.py runserver 4321
  ```
- Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and type `:wq` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

That's it